# forloop in flask code arguments not looping for the second position

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, flask, flask-restful

I am working on a use case to creating groups in AD through PyAD and create folder and groups for that folder through flask.

I am using for loop for passing arguments and returning responses. If the group exists code should not create if else it should create and then move on to create folder and set permissions.

But the logic works fine for for the first group passed in request, but 2nd one is not getting into the loop.

Facing issues making it work through flask and handle responses. Is there is a way to achive it, please help.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
#Class to create fileshare

class Test(Resource):
    def post(self):
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        # Get JSON arguments from Payload shared NAS path, directorname  groupname with read access and right access
        parentdir = request.json.get("shareUNCPath")
        dirname = request.json.get("shareFolderName")
        readGroup = request.json.get("readGroup")
        writeGroup = request.json.get("writeGroup")
        domainName = request.json.get("domain")
        groupList = [readGroup,writeGroup]
        #for gn in groupList:
        try:
            j=(len(groupList))+1
            if readGroup == writeGroup:
                j=(len(groupList))-1
            #for gn in len(groupList):
            for i in range(4):
                groupName = groupList[i]
                pyad.set_defaults(username="username", password="password", ldap_server="ldapServer")
                rGroup = adgroup.ADGroup.from_cn(groupName)
                logging.debug("read group {} available in AD ".format(groupName))
                if __name__ == "__main__":
                    os.makedirs(path)
                    igroup, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountName (domainName, groupName)
                    sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity(path, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
                    dacl = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()
                    logging.debug("Domain1 {}, Group1 {}".format(domainName, groupName))
                    if groupName in readGroup:                              
                        dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce(win32security.ACL_REVISION,con.GENERIC_READ, igroup)
                    if groupName in writeGroup:
                        dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce(win32security.ACL_REVISION,con.GENERIC_WRITE, igroup)
                    isdir = os.path.isdir(path)
                    if isdir == True:
                        sd.SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(1, dacl, 0)
                        win32security.SetFileSecurity(path, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, sd)
                        dacl = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()
                        cnt=dacl.GetAceCount()
                        for  i in range(0, cnt):
                            rev, access, usersid = dacl.GetAce(i)
                            user, group, type = win32security.LookupAccountSid(domainName, usersid)
                            details = ('Group: {}/{}'.format(group, user), rev,  access)))
                            resp = Response('Successfully created file share {}. Details {}'.format(dirname, details))
                            print (resp)
                                resp.status_code = 200
                                return resp

        except Exception as e:
            errormsg = str(e)
            print (errormsg)
            if "The server is not operational" in errormsg:
                resp = Response('AD operation failed, unable to connect to Active Directory. Error - {}'.format(e))
                print (resp)
                resp.status_code = 301
                return resp
            else:
                try:
                    for i in range(4):
                        groupName = groupList[i]  
                        pyad.set_defaults(username="username", password="pasword",ldap_server="ldapServer")
                        ou = pyad.adcontainer.ADContainer.from_dn(group_OU)
                        rGroup = adgroup.ADGroup.create(
                            name=groupName,
                            security_enabled = True,
                            scope=groupScope,
                            container_object=ou,
                            optional_attributes={"description": description}
                        )
                        if rGroup.Displayname == (groupName):                           
                            if __name__ == "__main__":
                                os.makedirs(path)
                                #groupr = win32security.LookupAccountName ("", readGroup)
                                a.logon()
                                time.sleep(5)
                                igroup, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountName (domainName, groupName)
                                sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity(path, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
                                #dacl = win32security.ACL()
                                dacl = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()
                                #acl = pywintypes.ACL()
                                #set permessions for readGroup with GENERIC_READ level permessions
                                #dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce(win32security.ACL_REVISION,con.GENERIC_READ, groupr)
                                if groupName in readGroup:
                                    dacl.AddAccessAllowedAceEx(win32security.ACL_REVISION,con.OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE|con.CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE,con.GENERIC_READ|con.GENERIC_EXECUTE, igroup)
                                if groupName in writeGroup:
                                    dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce(win32security.ACL_REVISION,con.GENERIC_WRITE, igroup)
                                isdir = os.path.isdir(path)
                                if isdir == True:
                                    sd.SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(1, dacl, 0)
                                    win32security.SetFileSecurity(path, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, sd)
                                    dacl = sd.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()
                                    cnt=dacl.GetAceCount()
                                    for  i in range(0, cnt):
                                        rev, access, usersid = dacl.GetAce(i)
                                        user, group, type = win32security.LookupAccountSid(domainName, usersid)
                                        details = ('Group: {}/{}'.format(group, user), rev,  access)
                                        #return ("Success Fileshare created: {} ".format(dirname))
                                        resp = Response('Successfully created file share {}. Details {}'.format(dirname, details))
                                        print (resp)
                                        resp.status_code = 200
                                        return resp

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                resp = Response('AD operation failed, unable to create to group {}. Error - {}'.format(groupName, e))
                print (resp)
                resp.status_code = 302
                return resp

api.add_resource(Test, '/test')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    #context = ('local.crt', 'local.key')#certificate and key files
    app.run(port="7050", host="0.0.0.0", use_reloader=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed your code. There are two things that should changed.

- You use `i` as the loop variable for the outer and inner loop
- In the first loop, you use an exception to trigger the group creation. This exits the loop and no more groups are processed. You should move the exception block inside the `range(4)` loop.

Here is your code with comments.

```
class Test(Resource):
    def post(self):
        .......
        try:
            ..........
            for i in range(4):  # using i as loop variable, loop will exit if exception
                ........
                if __ name __ == "__ main __":  # if group exists, update permissions, throws exception if group does not exist
                    ........
                    if isdir == True:
                        ........
                        for  i in range(0, cnt):  # using i as loop variable, again
                            .........

        # here is the problem - if the first group does not exist, an exception is thrown and the other groups are not processed
        except Exception as e:   # group does not exist, must add # You should move this inside the for loop
            ............
                try:
                    for i in range(4):  # using i as loop variable
                        ...........
                        if rGroup.Displayname == (groupName):                           
                            if __ name __ == "__main__":
                                .........
                                if isdir == True:
                                    ........
                                    for  i in range(0, cnt):  # using i as loop variable, again
                                        ..........
```

To clarify, the overall logic should be like this:

```
for i in range(4):  # each group
    try:
         # update permissions
    except Exception as e:
         # add new group
```

As a side note, try to check if the group exists without using the try\except block. Exceptions should not be used in normal program flow.